# onmousedown play sound

Tags: javascript, audio, onmousedown

How do I make a function in JavaScript that `onmousedown` in a specific elemtent executes this:

```
document.getElementById('KeyOfC').play();
```

and on `mouseup` executes this:

```
document.getElementById('KeyOfC').pause(); 
document.getElementById('null').play();
```

I'd be happy for any answers, as I'm new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just bind those triggers to the element (in this case it has an `id` of `foo`):

```
document.getElementById('foo').onmousedown = function()
{
  document.getElementById('KeyOfC').play();
}

document.getElementById('foo').onmouseup = function()
{
  document.getElementById('KeyOfC').pause(); 
  document.getElementById('null').play();
}
```

---

If you want to specify multiple `id`s (from your comment), you'd need a JavaScript library which does this. I'd recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('#foo, #bar, #foobar').mousedown(function()
{
  $('#KeyOfC').play();
});

$('#foo, #bar, #foobar').mouseup(function()
{
  $('#KeyOfC').pause();
  $('#null').play();
});
```

If you've done CSS, you can use CSS rules as [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), like `.ClassName, #your_id, etc.`.

Comment: can i use multiple ids in that? like document.getElementById('keyc, keyD, keyE').onmousedown = function()
{
  document.getElementById('KeyOfC, KeyOfDm KeyOfE').play();
}

Comment: Like what? `id` attributes refer to only *one* element in the HTML, like `<p id="foo">Foo</p>`, so you can't have two elements with an `id` of `foo`. But `document.getElementById('foo')` is just finding that specific element and setting it's `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` properties to perform certain tasks. Yes, you can :P

Comment: Whoops, missed your edit. No, you can't. If you want to do that, you'd need a JS library. I'd recommend jQuery: http://jquery.com/.

Comment: Can I do so that i dont need the have that code like 8 times for each Key or can I somehow make the code smaller with some other JavaScript thingys?

Comment: how would i do that in jwuery? :P

Comment: See my edit. jQuery is a really simple JS library which lets you do things like this, and simplifies *tons* of JavaScript functions (like AJAX).

Comment: IS jquiery code stored in a .js file? Is it just to type that code in a .js file and put src to that .js and jwuery .js?

Comment: jQuery is a huge JavaScript file which is based around a function (the dollar sign, but you can also use `jQuery()`). It's just JavaScript, nothing more. It's not it's own language, so use it like you would normal JavaScript.